# Deferred template string interpolation

Tags: c#, .net

In C# there is a string interpolation support like this:

```
$"Constant with {Value}"
```

which will format this string using in-scope variable `Value`.

But the following won't compile in current C# syntax.

Say, I have a static `Dictionary<string, string>` of templates:

```
templates = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Key1", $"{Value1}" },
    { "Key2", $"Constant with {Value2}" }
}
```

And then on every run of this method I want to fill in the placeholders:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> FillTemplate(IDictionary<string, string> placeholderValues)
{
    return templates.ToDictionary(
        t => t.Key,
        t => string.FormatByNames(t.Value, placeholderValues));
}
```

Is it achievable without implementing Regex parsing of those placeholders and then a replace callback on that Regex?
What are the most performant options that can suit this method as being a hot path?

For example, it is easily achievable in Python:

```
>>> templates = { "Key1": "{Value1}", "Key2": "Constant with {Value2}" }
>>> values = { "Value1": "1", "Value2": "example 2" }
>>> result = dict(((k, v.format(**values)) for k, v in templates.items()))
>>> result
{'Key2': 'Constant with example 2', 'Key1': '1'}
>>> values2 = { "Value1": "another", "Value2": "different" }
>>> result2 = dict(((k, v.format(**values2)) for k, v in templates.items()))
>>> result2
{'Key2': 'Constant with different', 'Key1': 'another'}
```

Comment: Internally, Python's `format` must be using a Regular Expression, what do you have against using one?

Comment: My initial implementation is using Regex and is slow, showing high contention on Regex matching. I surely could leave it like that, but this method is the hot path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an extension method that does a substitution based on regular expressions, I get a good speed up over using multiple `Replace` calls for each value.

Here is my extension method for expanding brace surrounded variables:

```
public static class ExpandExt {
    static Regex varPattern = new Regex(@"{(?<var>\w+)}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public static string Expand(this string src, Dictionary<string, string> vals) => varPattern.Replace(src, m => vals.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out var v) ? v : m.Value);
}
```

And here is the sample code using it:

```
var ans = templates.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.Expand(values));
```

Over 10,000 repeating expansions with `values` at 18 entries and typically only one replacement, I get 3x faster than multiple `String.Replace` calls.

Comment: Use `RegexOptions.Compiled`. You'll probably get a speed up as well

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Changes from about 3x faster to about 3.5x faster.

Comment: My Regex was a bit different (`\\{([^}]*)\\}`), and it didn't have the Compiled flag. So Regex is actually better than string Replace. I'll mark this accepted.

Comment: This is a great way to solve it, however, the code sample was not complete to try it out instantly - so I am providing a .Net fiddle **[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oJEpbz)** for those, who are interested.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible, instead you should use [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format).

With String format your string template would look like `string template = "The temperature is {0}°C."` and then to insert the value you could just:

```
decimal temp = 20.4m;
string s = String.Format(template, temp);
```

As shown in the Microsoft examples.

Comment: string interpolation uses string.format essentially .. AFAIK

Comment: From your example, it moves towards positional format.
Notice that the template dictionary had `{Value1}` and `{Value2}` placeholders in different values, so they both look like `{0}`, but should apply different values from placeholderValues dictionary.
I guess I could have `Tuple<string, string[]>("{0}", new[] { "Value1" })` and then use it to prepare a formatting array.
Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a cleaner way, you must declare both the template and the object array somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best alternative to Regular Expressions is doing `Replace` on each possible Value key, but which is faster would depend on how many values you have and how common replacements for those values are.

```
var templates = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "Key1", "{Value1}" },
    { "Key2", "Constant with {Value2}" }
};

var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Value1", "1" }, { "Value2", "example 2" } };

var ans = templates.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => values.Aggregate(kv.Value, (s, v) => s.Replace($"{{{v.Key}}}", v.Value)));
```

Note that a `foreach` instead of `Aggregate` would be marginally faster, again depending on how many entries are in `values`. Also, pre-building new key and values `Array`s with key already surrounded by braces can bring about a 4x speedup, but we are talking about milliseconds in your example.

```
var subkeys = values.Select(kv => $"{{{kv.Key}}}").ToArray();
var subvals = values.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToArray();

var ans4 = templates.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => {
    var final = kv.Value;
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < subkeys.Length; ++j1)
        final = final.Replace(subkeys[j1], subvals[j1]);
    return final;
});
```

Of course, if your `values` array changes with each method call, using two `List`s with braces around the keys would be a better storage structure as translating every time will eat up the time savings.

Comment: `values` dictionary is expected to have 15-20 keys. Executed your Aggregate example on a unit test - got around ten times speed up and no contentions in profiling (comparing to Regex). Looking into this direction.

Comment: @SergeyIonov Running a Regex on an expanded example using a `values` with 18 keys without braces versus `Aggregate` and it was 3X faster. I'll post it as another answer.